# Help for thin flavorless jam

Tags: canning, jam

I made a blackberry/blueberry jam about 3 1/2 weeks ago.  Due to work and school, I lost track of time.  The jam came out a little thin (and flavorless).  Is it too late to reprocess the jars?  It was a double batch so I have about 13 jars.  I haven't found anything that says how long you can (or have to) wait before reprocessing.  Most articles say wait two weeks to see if it sets up and then reprocess if needed but doesn't say the max "wait" time.  The recipe I used was simple:  X cups of fruit, X cups of sugar,  and 2 pkgs low sugar pectin (since it was a double batch).

Any help is appreciated!  :)

Brooke

Answer (score 3):

As long as the jars sealed, and the product is *safely* canned, you can open and recan if you desire.

Comment: Thank you.  :)  I may not remember to taste the scalding hot liquid before canning it, but I always make sure it's canned for at least 10-15 minutes (depending on what I'm canning).  :)

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear what you mean with 'reprocessing'.

If you intend to transfer it into another jar, even if the product was safely canned, you loose the vacuum so you cannot store it anymore.

In any case a suggestion for the recipe: you are making proportion in a volum based way (cups), while the most proper way would be to make proportions with weight. 
So, for instance, X kilos (grams) of fruit, X kilos (grams) of sugar etc...

tnx to ll

Comment: 'reprocessing' usually includes repeating the whole canning process, to get a vacuum seal on the new jar.

Comment: @ Daniele - I am in the U.S.  Most of our recipes are in cups and ounces since we use the Imperial system for weighing and measuring.  While in most of the world your system would be more proper, I wouldn't be able to make my recipe using metric without all new measuring cups, spoons, etc.  :)